# scripts are not adding

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am adding some scripts but it is throwing error that $ is not defined.

```
$data['announces']=$this->Admin_model->get_announcements();
$this->load->view('templates/admin/header');
$this->load->view('layouts/admin/announcement',$data);
$this->load->view('templates/admin/footer');
```

and in the view i did this

```
<script src="<?=AdminAssets ?>js/annoucement.js"></script>
```

But if I add footer.php in the view and after that add script it works fine.

```
 <?php $this->load->view('templates/admin/footer');   ?>  
 <script src="<?=AdminAssets ?>js/annoucement.js"></script>
```

Actually I can't find the difference between these two methodologies because in every case order of statements is same.

Comment: right click on the page. view source. the footer view includes your libraries? wondering if theres a race condition maybe with a script loader?

Comment: The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** and a **Network** tab. What does the generated HTML look like? Also, please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested?

Comment: thanks to both of you. Actually I found the solution. I was adding footer in the end and in layouts/admin/announcement I was adding my script i.e annoucement.js. I think when announcement view added it can't get the reference of jquery and throws error in announcement.js.

Comment: i added the footer first after that i added announcement view then it worked !!!

Answer (score -2):

check the source of the rendered page. im guessing `the script src=".../jquery.js" comes after your code actualy calling jquery.

$ not defined just says that you're doing something like $("#id") before loading the jquery.js file

edit: following the conversation bellow.

my answer is TL;DR jquery isnt being loaded yet when you call jquery code.

the longer version:

im guessing (yeah go ahead and downvote) that the framework injects the required libraries / global scripts after the footer view gets called. or the footer view includes the scripts as a destructor. so actually putting your script src="..." in the footer view would technicaly include it before the "trigger" has been added.

```
header
body
footer
scripts
```

you are now doing

```
header
body
footer
  script
scripts
```

Comment: Please don't guess. Ask for clarification with comments.

Comment: thanks for your response.I know this error occurs when jquery is not loaded but i can't figure out that how in the second piece of code it is working fine because order of statement is same in both pieces of code.

Comment: well OP didnt include the html of the rendered page so we have no real way of knowing right? but it still stands that $ not defined is that he/she is calling the jquery code BEFORE including the jquery library. only way to know is to check the order it gets rendered in

Comment: @WilliamStam Then ask for the html with a comment. I know that's the most probable cause, but it's not certain.

Comment: lol the answers that jquery isnt loaded are the correct answer "why" its happening. but not the correct answer of "how do i fix this". so you are quite mistaken there im afraid.

Comment: @WilliamStam i have give link of jquery in my footer.php so after adding footer.php if I add <script src="<?=AdminAssets ?>js/annoucement.js"></script> it should work .....but it is not working and in second piece of code all goes in a right way.

Comment: @mozzam not sure how codeignitor injects the required libraries. is it using something like requirejs?

Comment: @WilliamStam judging from the other downvote and the two upvotes to my comment, it looks like I'm not the only one to think that.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca internet trolls will be internet trolls. SO is no different

Comment: @mozzam the other dev here uses YII. it has some trigger that loads the required libraries (i dont know what that trigger is). 

my guess (shock horror) is that the trigger is on finally loading the footer since script tags are usualy right before the closing body tag. so the framework goes "woohoo we loaded the footer view i can now include the libraries". since you're including your JS file in the footer the trigger hasnt "run" yet. so jquery.js is loaded after that